# как добавить значение в поле из другой таблицы?(liquibase)

Tags: java, sql, liquibase

Пытаюсь сделать миграцию через liquibase.

У меня есть две таблицы, "users" и "roles". С начало создаю таблицы и заполняю роли. Потом пытаюсь добавить changeSet с insert для заполнения юзера. Мне необходимо при добавлении юзера, взять из таблицы роли id который соответствует заданном  значению(admin).

Я делаю пытаюсь сделать через вставку sql.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `role_id`=(SELECT `roles`.`id`) WHERE `roles`.`role`='admin'
```

Но поле role_id у меня есть параметр notNull. И из-за этого кидает ошибку при выполнении.

Собственно вопрос в том, как добавить значение role_id? (параметр в column не принимает, и в теги column тоже sql не принимает) и есть ли возможность добавить без вставки SQL.

```
        <changeSet author="eskosirskiy" id="USER_TABLE">
                <createTable tableName="users">
                    <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="surname" type="varchar(40)">
                        <constraints nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="name" type="varchar(20)">
                        <constraints nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="midleName" type="varchar(40)"/>
                    <column name="email" type="varchar(50)">
                        <constraints unique="true" nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="password" type="varchar(255)">
                        <constraints nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="role_id" type="BIGINT">
                        <constraints nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                    <column name="isdelete" type="varchar(5)" defaultValueBoolean="false">
                        <constraints nullable="false"/>
                    </column>
                </createTable>
            </changeSet>

        <changeSet author="eskosirskiy" id="ROLE_TABLE">
            <createTable tableName="roles">
                <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                </column>
                <column name="role" type="varchar(15)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                </column>
            </createTable>
        </changeSet>
<changeSet id="eskosirskiy" author="insert_in_users_table">
        <insert tableName="users">
            <column name="surname" value="surnameadmin"/>
            <column name="name" value="nameadmin"/>
            <column name="midlename" value="midlenameadmin"/>
            <column name="email" value="admin@ya.ru"/>
            <column name="password" value="$2a$12$8SrXhKwtjhUsaKDX70qD2eoXPI4gTL1KwNkmQxEB75hmulx/wsjFy"/>
            <column name="role_id"/>
        </insert>
        <sql>UPDATE `users` SET `role_id`=(SELECT `roles`.`id`) WHERE `roles`.`role`='admin'</sql>
    </changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<column name="role_id" valueComputed="(SELECT id FROM roles WHERE role = 'admin')"/>
```